Laravel Package Development - Need to extend the FormRequest class, but don't want to require the entire laravel framework package
Introduction
I am developing a Laravel package that will generate request rules based on the EditorJS blocks present in the request. To offer maximum developer convenience, i offer a EditorJSFormRequest class that extends the FormRequest class. This class builds the rules for defined block types, and can then be used as a regular FormRequest class inside a controller function.
My Problem
The FormRequest class comes from Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest, which unfortunately isn't a standalone package, but requires the entire laravel/framework package. To me, requiring the entire framework seems like a bad practice, and i wonder if there is any other way. If not, i am already doubting if my solution is coded in a logical manner, meaning i also wonder if i need to change the entire code.
Context
Given that i am starting to doubt if i am on the right path, i want to offer some context to give you an idea what i am doing, this is the EditorJSFormRequest class code:
namespace FurisonTech\LaraveditorJS;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

abstract class EditorJSFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected array $editorJSFieldRuleBuilders = [];

    /**
     * EditorJSFormRequest constructor.
     * @param array<EditorJSRequestFieldRuleBuilder> $editorJSFieldRuleBuilders
     */
    public function __construct(array $editorJSFieldRuleBuilders = [])
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->editorJSFieldRuleBuilders = $editorJSFieldRuleBuilders;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     * @return array
     */
    final public function rules(): array
    {
        $rules = [];

        // Build rules for each Editor.js field
        foreach ($this->editorJSFieldRuleBuilders as $builder) {
            $rules = array_merge($rules, $builder->buildRules($this));
        }

        // Merge with additional rules
        return array_merge($rules, $this->additionalRules());
    }

    /**
     * Additional validation rules.
     * @return array
     */
    abstract protected function additionalRules(): array;
}

Now a developer can create a class that extends EditorJSFormRequest instead of FormRequest, like:
class SaveArticleRequest extends EditorJSFormRequest
{

    private const ALLOWED_EMBED_SERVICES = ['youtube', 'twitter', 'instagram', 'facebook', 'imgur'];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct([
            new EditorJSRequestFieldRuleBuilder('article', [
                'table' => new TableBlockRulesSupplier(200, 20, 255, 3),
                'header' => new HeaderBlockRulesSupplier(255, null),
                'paragraph' => new ParagraphBlockRulesSupplier(2500, null),
                'image' => new ImageBlockRulesSupplier(255, 10),
                'audioPlayer' => new AudioPlayerBlockRulesSupplier(12),
                'embed' => new EmbedBlockRulesSupplier(self::ALLOWED_EMBED_SERVICES, 255, 5),
                'list' => new ListBlockRulesSupplier(100, 500, null),
            ])
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected function additionalRules(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}

Is it okay to require the laravel/framework package for this cause or should i do this another way?

If the request functionality is only available through the entire framework and not as a standalone package, what users are you trying to please by only requiring the request? If all potential users are required to pull in the framework anyway, what benefit are you trying to gain by not doing so in your package?

@NicklasKevinFrank i think you make a great point with your (rethorical?) question. the only thing that is left that bugs me is that users of lumen (a microframework of laravel) might get a lot of unnecessary dependencies. But i am not sure about that one to be honest, i never used lumen. For now i will just require the laravel/framework package.

I think the major reason why it's not part of standalone package is because the automatic validation from the rules method only actually happens when you use the entire Laravel request/response functionality so is not really meaningful to provide standalone

@Estoo valid point regarding Lumen - as a note Lumen is deprecated https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/11.x, that said there might be reasons you want to accommodate older versions specifically.
I am afraid I don't have a good answer to the issue besides above.

Use orchestra/testbench to develop packages for Laravel.
https://github.com/orchestral/testbench
Use illuminate/support to restrict the Laravel version.
This is the minimum knowledge required for package developers.
  "require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
    "illuminate/support": "^10.0||^11.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "orchestra/testbench": "^8.0||^9.0"
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "providers": [
        "My\\Package\\MyServiceProvider"
      ]
    }
  },

FormRequest is always present in Laravel, so you don't need to worry about it.
Lumen no longer needs to be supported.
